# Origine di 'a vanvera'

Tags: etymology

L'espressione  *[a vanvera](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/vanvera.shtml)* è molto comune e significa:

> - a casaccio, senza riflettere, ed è usata soprattutto nell'espressione: parlare a vanvera.

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20vanvera&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20vanvera%3B%2Cc0) la locuzione ha cominciato  a diventare sempre più usata  dall'inizio del 1800. Altre fonti la fanno risalire al XVI secolo.

Sull'[origine](http://etimoitaliano.blogspot.it/2014/03/vanvera.html) di questo modo di dire ci sono varie ipotesi, una di queste molto curiosa:

> - 1)  Alcuni riconducono l'etimologia di vanvera **all'antico lemma onomatopeico fanfera dal suono fan-fan  (da cui fanfarone = chiacchierone, spaccone, sbruffone, millantatore)**.
> - 2)  Altro etimo, **dallo spagnolo bambàra dall'omonimo gioco di carte**, a sua volta da bambarria che nel gioco del biliardo indica un tiro sbagliato ma casualmente vincente. Per cui, chi parla a vanvera è colui che parla a casaccio, diremmo con una perifrasi moderna, chi utilizza le labbra senza connetterle col cervello...
> - 3) Una meno diffusa ma non meno interessante etimologia del termine vanvera riconduce l'etimo ad **uno strumento in uso nel Seicento presso i Veneziani che era chiamato appunto vanvera: si trattava di un contenitore per i gas intestinali utilizzato da chi soffrisse di meteorismi incontrollabili,** che permetteva di scaricare, anche in pubblico, ed immagazzinare momentaneamente tali miasmi un un sacchetto di pelle, e di scaricarli successivamente, una volta non in presenza di altre persone!

Quale tra queste, o eventualmente altre, potrebbe essere la più affidabile origine di questo termine curioso ma molto comune?

Comment: Sarei proprio curioso di sapere da dove quel sito ha preso la terza ipotesi (o se l'hanno tirata fuori un po' a vanvera...).

Comment: @DaG - la vanvera veneziana sembra essere una cosa che veniva effettivamente usata: http://www.merdasser.it/La%20vanvera/La%20vanvera%20it.htm

Answer (score 4):

Questa [fonte](https://books.google.es/books?id=x9U9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA175&dq=vanvera&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TL3XVIugDPO0sATpsYKICQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=vanvera&f=false) sembra concordare con la prima ipotesi. Ma quest'[altro libro del 1840](https://books.google.es/books?id=WxFaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA11&dq=bambera&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Lb_XVOKtCs7jsASb2IGwCg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=bambera&f=false) afferma che il modo avverbiale "*a vanvera*" è anche detto "*a bambera*" e "*a fanfera"*. Il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bambara/) conferma che "*bambara*" è un gioco di carte e che si tratta di una parola proveniente dallo spagnolo "*bambarria*" ("tiro sbagliato ma fortunato" nel biliardo).

Answer (score 2):

Il Dizionario etimologico online pare [concordare con la tua prima ipotesi](http://www.etimo.it/?term=vanvera). Le altre due sono interessanti (specialmente la terza) ma credo la prima regga senza bisogno di folklore.